# Controller Action Redirects from Derived Controller class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Base controller class in my application derived from System.Web.Mvc.Controller Base class.
In the overriden method "ActionResultExecuting" i have my business Logic, to check for the existence of the Authentication cookie.
If the current request does not have the Authentication Cookie / Satisfy my business condition, i need to redirect the request to the Logout action and then to the Login action.

Please find my code snippet

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ///... User story 1 - Domain1 Cookie present and Domain2 cookie present - Session ID references match in both the cookies
        HttpCookie Domain1Cookie= filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["dm1"];
        HttpCookie Domain2Cookie= filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["dm2"];

        if (Domain1Cookie != null && Domain2Cookie != null)
        {
            string eacCookieValue = Domain1Cookie.Value;
            string enrollmentCookieValue = Domain2Cookie.Value;
            if (eacCookieValue.Contains(enrollmentCookieValue))
            {
                string controllerName = RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
                string actionName = RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();

                if (controllerName != "Account" && actionName != "Login")
                {
                    ////... This is where i need to put my redirection code... Redirect the User to LogOut Action and then redirect to Login
                }

            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }       
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `filterContext.Result` property to a `RedirectToRouteResult` indicating the controller and action you are willing to redirect. You could obviously pass any additional route values and query string parameters you like:

```
if (controllerName != "Account" && actionName != "Login")
{
    ////... This is where i need to put my redirection code... Redirect the User to LogOut Action and then redirect to Login
    var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = "Account",
        action = "LogOut"
    });
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
}
```

But a more correct way to achieve this is to override the [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onauthorization.aspx) method instead of `OnActionExecuting`.